# Convert packed string of bytes from protobuf to formatted via logstash

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

I've got a protobuf that I'm trying to feed through logstash. Some of the values look binary formatted:

When printing through the `rubydebug` codec

I'm getting values like:

```
rData => '\xD8:\xC9$'
```

This appears to be because by `protobuf` template has:

```
optional :bytes, :rData, 5
```

Which ... does what it says on the tin - hands the raw bytes through to logstash, which then assumes they are text.

So, that `rData` line would decode as `216.58.201.36` which is the response for `www.google.com`.

How can I convert this into a useful format in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this, you will need to write a bit of ruby yourself.

But don't worry, it's easier than it sounds, you can just inline ruby into the logstash config file.

First:

- Set your output codec to `rubydebug` so it prints the data structure - you'll need this to identify which fields you want.

So for my example (snipped for brevity):

We are interested in the `rData` field.

```
"socketProtocol" => 1,
    "@timestamp" => 2017-12-12T10:26:41.910Z,
   "requestorId" => "",
          "port" => 47788,
      "response" => {
            "rcode" => 0,
              "rrs" => [
        [0] {
             "rType" => 1,
             "rData" => "\xD8:\xC9$",
            "rClass" => 1,
             "rName" => "www.google.com.",
              "rTtl" => 300
        }
    ],
```

We also have a few examples of longer `rData` fields, where the value in rubydebug is:

```
"rData" => "*\x00\x14P@\t\b\v\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x04",
```

Which ends up rendering into Elasticsearch as:

```
"rData": "*\u0000\u0014P@\t\b\u000b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 \u0004",
```

So we extract this using `event.get("response")` so we can test the existence (necessary, because in my use case there'll be `response` fields with no data):

```
filter {
  if [response] {
    ruby {
      code => 

        # response rData can be a different things.
        #usually an ipV4 address, or an ipv6. 
        #But they're usually written in different formats - ipv4 is dotted quads,
        #where ipv6 is hex and double-bytes
        #so we look at the (unpacked) string length, and see if there are 4 (or more) 'uint64s' in there. 
        #and substitute accordingly. 
        '
        response = event.get("response")
        if ( response and response["rrs"] and response["rrs"][0] and response["rrs"][0]["rData"] ) 
           rdata = response["rrs"][0]["rData"]
           hex_value = rdata.unpack("H*").join("")
           ip_value =  rdata.unpack("C4").join(".")
           length_rdata =    rdata.unpack("L*").length
           if ( length_rdata >= 4 ) 
             event.set("[response][decoded_rdata]", hex_value )
           else
             event.set("[response][decoded_rdata]", ip_value) 
           end
        end
       '
    }
  }
}
```

Note - this tests the length of the `rData` value, and if it's "long" then assumes it's an ipv6 address and formats as hex, and if it's short, assumes that it's ipv4 and formats as the conventional 'dotted' quad.

It then adds to a new subfield, `response.decoded_rdata` which is probably more useful for elasticsearch than nesting any deeper.

We also have an additional snippet to handle the 'byte' encoding of the `from`/`to`/`messageId` field which is largely similar:

```
  ruby {
    code =>  
       #take to and from fields, and assume they're packed IP addresses. 
       #take messageId and convert to hex. 
       'event.set("from", event.get("from").unpack("C4").join("."));
        event.set("to", event.get("to").unpack("C4").join("."));
        event.set("messageId", event.get("messageId").unpack("H*").join(""));
       '
  }
```